# Facebook Open Graph Tags not working correctly in a simple Html

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to use Facebook Open Graph meta tags for my site. I want my links to be showed correctly when I share them in Facebook. But it doesn't. When I test the link in [Facebook Debuger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) but it always shows `Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.`. I searched a lot and read the Facebook's documentation about good examples and followed them. But no success. Here is my Page Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>تست</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="www.kaladaran.com">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="Product">
<meta name="description" content="Product">
<!--FACEBOOK-->
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Test">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Kaladaran">
<meta property="og:url" content="www.kaladaran.com/test.html">
<meta property="og:description" content="Descritption">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="My App Id">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://kaladaran.com/Data/1598/6ccec951-f124-43f6-abb0-a59e3d94bd67.jpg">    
<meta property="og:image:width" content="250px">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="169px">
<meta property="og:locale" content="fa_IR"><meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/KDAdsCo" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/KDAdsCo" />

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>
            Facebook Open Graph Tag Test
        </h1>
        <img src="http://kaladaran.com/Data/1598/6ccec951-f124-43f6-abb0-    a59e3d94bd67.jpg" alt="Panasonic" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't understand what is wrong with my code? Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Are you mistakenly giving https url?

Comment: No. I give the Url without Http:// or Https://

Comment: Your live site lacks a number of required attributes. http://imgur.com/n9Yysj0

Comment: What attributes? By the way this page link is www.kaladaran.com/test.html

Comment: Ok, try putting http:// before the url

Answer (score 0):

The line:

`<link rel="canonical" href="www.kaladaran.com”>` is causing the error. A canonical link is meant to point to the *current* page, **not** the home page.

Also, note that, the URL inside a `<link>` is **relative** if you leave out the http:// which is why you are getting the error.

Make it like :

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.kaladaran.com/test.html">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.kaladaran.com/test.html">`

Also, remember to type the exact same URL in the Facebook scraper.

When Facebook finds a canonical link that points to a different URL, *it will treat it like a redirect* .

From Facebook:

> The following will be treated as a redirect by the crawler:
>
> A HTTP redirect
>
> A `<link rel="canonical" href=".." />` tag
>
> A `<meta property="og:url" content=".." />` tag

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element

Comment: I fixed that issue but still getting this error: "Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped". It does not recognize the og:title, og:image, og:description

Comment: @Beginner remove the canonical tag entirely and try please.

Comment: It does not scrape it. I can see that last scrape time is an hour a ago.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not scrape again.

Comment: Did you make the two changes ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81110/discussion-between-beginner-and-rishav-kundu).

Comment: @Beginner please check the chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81110/discussion-between-beginner-and-rishav-kundu

Comment: @Beginner I am willing to help you, but you are not giving me feedback.